# How I write to the file from datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, xmlwriter

Am trying to write from the datagridview with a goal of saving the input to the xml file, but am not getting it correctly. My code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(outputFilePath);
doc.Save(outputFilePath);
oDataSet = new DataSet();

foreach (DataGridViewRow _rows in Gridview_Output.Rows)
{
    DataRow oDatarow = oDataTable.NewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < Gridview_Output.ColumnCount; i++)
    {
        oDataTable.Rows.Add(oDatarow.ItemArray);
    }
}
oDataSet.Tables.Add(oDataTable);
oDataSet.WriteXml(outputFilePath);
doc.Save(outputFilePath);
```

I want to write to this empty tags:

```
<data name="Exit_Button" xml:space="preserve">
<value></value>
<comment>[Font][/Font][DateStamp][/DateStamp][Comment][/Comment]</comment>
</data>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm try this to create a datatable from gridview:

```
private DataTable GetDataTableFromDGV(DataGridView dgv) {

    var dt = new DataTable();
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv.Columns) {
        if (column.Visible) {
            // You could potentially name the column based on the DGV column name (beware of dupes)
            // or assign a type based on the data type of the data bound to this DGV column.
            dt.Columns.Add();
        }
    }
    object[] cellValues = new object[dgv.Columns.Count];
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows) {
        for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++) {
            cellValues[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
        }
            dt.Rows.Add(cellValues);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
DataTable dT = GetDataTableFromDGV(DataGridView1);
DataSet dS = new DataSet();
dS.Tables.Add(dT);
dS.WriteXml(File.OpenWrite("xml.xml"));
```

Comment: from the commented part, can you please give me an example like coding  as example then i will change for it meet my needs

Comment: what do you mean by coding as example? this is coding

Comment: how i can potentially name the column based on the DGV ?

Comment: write down the column name name in dt.Columns.Add("ColumnName"), is that what you are aksing?